# PHP preg_replace match HTML attribute

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm attempting to remove the title attribute from HTML elements.

```
function remove_title_attributes($input) {
    return remove_html_attribute('title', $input);
}

/**
 * To remove an attribute from an html tag
 * @param string $attr the attribute
 * @param string $str the html
 */
function remove_html_attribute($attr, $str){
    return preg_replace('/\s*'.$attr.'\s*=\s*(["\']).*?\1/', '', $str);
}
```

However, it can't tell the difference between `<img title="something">` and `[shortcode title="something"]`. How can I target only the code in HTML tags (such as `<img>` or `<a href=""><a>`)?

Comment: use a HTML parser for this, not regex functions.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

Comment: When I use this function, I don't have a fully-formed HTML document. Just the body content of a blog post without a root tag. Something like this: `<p>stuff <a href="link" title="something">linkme</a></p><p>more stuff</p><p>even more stuff</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code from @Hast as a building block. It looks like this does the trick (unless there's a better way?)

```
/**
 * To remove an attribute from an html tag
 * @param string $attr the attribute
 * @param string $str the html
 */
function remove_html_attribute($attr, $input){
    //return preg_replace('/\s*'.$attr.'\s*=\s*(["\']).*?\1/', '', $input);

    $result='';

    if(!empty($input)){

        //check if the input text contains tags
        if($input!=strip_tags($input)){
            $dom = new DOMDocument();

            //use mb_convert_encoding to prevent non-ASCII characters from randomly appearing in text
            $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($input, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

            $domElement = $dom->documentElement;

            $taglist = array('a', 'img', 'span', 'li', 'table', 'td'); //tags to check for specified tag attribute

            foreach($taglist as $target_tag){
                $tags = $domElement->getElementsByTagName($target_tag);

                foreach($tags as $tag){
                    $tag->removeAttribute($attr);
                }
            }

            //$result =  $dom->saveHTML();
            $result = innerHTML( $domElement->firstChild ); //strip doctype/html/body tags
        }
        else{
            $result=$input;
        }
    }

    return $result; 
}

/**
 * removes the doctype/html/body tags
 */
function innerHTML($node){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));

  return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use regexp, use a DOM parser instead. Go the the [official reference page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and study it. In your case you need the [DOMElement::removeAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php) method. Here is an example:

```
<?php

$html = '<p>stuff <a href="link" title="something">linkme</a></p><p>more stuff</p><p>even more stuff</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$domElement = $dom->documentElement;

$a = $domElement->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
$a->removeAttribute('title');

$result =  $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there is no root tag. The HTML code I'm working with is the content for a page or blog post. For example, the HTML code I have is something like this: `<p>stuff <a href="link" title="something">linkme</a></p><p>more stuff</p><p>even more stuff</p>`

Comment: You say "you need the DOMNode::removeChild() method" but in your code you used removeAttribute

Comment: @naomi yes, sorry, it was just a mistake.

Comment: When the <a> tag doesn't exist, I get this: `Fatal error: Call to a member function removeAttribute() on a non-object`. Can I target all tags, or do I have to specify tags on an individual basis?

Comment: @ForceFlow error shown because you have to check if the title attribute exists in the element using hasAttribure method. Yes, you can. Write a recursive function that will loop throgh all html elements. Or use DOMXPath query: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php